# Did the ruling in "Measure of a Man" have any effect beyond Data?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, laws

In light of later episodes and *Picard*, I am confused as to whether the effect of the ruling of the hearing in the *TNG* episode "Measure of a Man" was strictly confined *inter partes* or if it had any precedential (or, if the Federation is more civil law, *res judicata*) effect or binding force on other cases involving artificial intelligence? (Such as with the Exocomps or the Doctor from *VOY*)  Did the ruling serve to liberate *all* androids of sufficient intelligence, or just Data?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! While you're here, please do take the [tour] and browse the [help] if you need to find out more how the site works. This is a really good question at first glance, and we get an excellent answer to it at well

Comment: In the EU novels, the ruling and its legal implications are referenced in considerable detail

Comment: While it was quoted to counter the Admiral trying to take custody of Lal - it obviously wasn't strong enough to make Starfleet realize it was a bad idea in general to treat Androids as property.

Answer (score 1):

The particular question in [Measure of a Man](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/135.htm) was put as thus

> I've got to make a ruling, to try to speak to the future. Is Data a machine? Yes. Is he the property of Starfleet? No.

Remember, Data wasn't just an android, he was also a Starfleet officer. As such, Starfleet was ruled to not own Data. Which means this ruling only applies to androids serving in Starfleet.

There's also a dearth of sentient androids to know for sure, but we do at least have some idea from later canon. We see in the *Star Trek: Picard* episode [Maps and Legends](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=986&t=40822) that [A500 androids](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A500) (**spoiler note:** that page contains a significant *Picard spoiler*) do not have higher reasoning, nor are they members of Starfleet. Thus they appear to be the property of Starfleet.